# Getting portion of Image using PixelReader/PixelWriter JavaFX

Tags: java, image, javafx

I'm trying to get a portion of an Image using JavaFX, but the code fails when `y = 1`.

Here is the code:

```
public static Image crop(Image src, int col, int row) {
    PixelReader r = src.getPixelReader();
    int sx = col * Grid.SIZE; // start x
    int sy = row * Grid.SIZE; // start y
    int ex = sx + Grid.SIZE;  // end x
    int ey = sy + Grid.SIZE;  // end y
    int rx = 0; // x to be written
    int ry = 0; // y to be written

    System.out.println(sx + ", " + sy + ", " + ex + ", " + ey);

    WritableImage out = new WritableImage(Grid.SIZE, Grid.SIZE);
    PixelWriter w = out.getPixelWriter();

    for(int y = sy; y < ey; y++, ry++) {
        for(int x = sx; x < ex; x++, rx++) {
            int c = r.getArgb(x, y);
            w.setArgb(rx, ry, c);
            System.out.println(rx + ", " + ry + ", " + x + ", " + y);
        }   
    }
    return out;
}
```

Everything goes well, until the `y`'s in the loop become 1, then this happens:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 32, 1
    at com.sun.prism.Image$BaseAccessor.getIndex(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.prism.Image$BaseAccessor.setArgb(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.prism.Image.setArgb(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.image.WritableImage$2.setArgb(Unknown Source)
```

I have no idea what is wrong. I will give any other information I can.

Comment: Can you explain what `Grid.SIZE` is and what `col` and `row` are supposed to represent in this method? Typically to crop you would expect a start x and y, a width, and height. Two parameters doesn't seem enough.

Comment: @James_D `Grid.SIZE` equals 32. It is supposed to represent the width and height of the image to be cropped, and the `col` and `row` are the column and row to start cropping on

Comment: So why are you doing `sx = col * Grid.SIZE`?

Comment: To get the starting position of the crop. It is supposed to be cropping a spritesheet. If `col` equals 1, the crop will start at `x = 32`.

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't understand what you meant by "row and column to start cropping on".

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the index out of bounds exception because you're not resetting `rx` to `0` when you begin each new row.

However, if you want a `Grid.SIZE` by `Grid.SIZE` crop of `src`, starting at `(col, row)`, the easier (and potentially better-performing) way to do it is:

```
public static Image crop(Image src, int col, int row) {
    PixelReader r = src.getPixelReader();
    PixelFormat<IntBuffer> pixelFormat = PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance() ;
    int[] pixels = new int[Grid.SIZE * Grid.SIZE];
    r.getPixels(col * Grid.SIZE, row * Grid.SIZE, Grid.SIZE, Grid.SIZE, pixelFormat,
        pixels, 0, Grid.SIZE);
    WritableImage out = new WritableImage(Grid.SIZE, Grid.SIZE);
    PixelWriter w = out.getPixelWriter();
    w.setPixels(0, 0, Grid.SIZE, Grid.SIZE, pixelFormat,
        pixels, 0, Grid.SIZE);
    return out ;
}
```

Obviously this will fail if `(col+1)*Grid.SIZE > src.getWidth()` or `(row+1)*Grid.SIZE > src.getHeight()`, which you could check for in the method and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, with a few changes. `PixelFormat<IntBuffer>` should be `WritablePixelFormat<IntBuffer>`, and `PixelFormat.createIntArgbInstance()` to `PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance()`.

Comment: Oops, yes, fixed the method name. But you only need a `PixelFormat`, not a `WritablePixelFormat`. Also figured out why you are getting the exception.

Comment: Yes I just noticed that. It's good that it is better performing, because this method is running every time I get a sprite, and the game runs at 60 fps!